# Is there a way to independantly hillshade the overviews of a GeoTIFF pyramid in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, hillshade, image-pyramids

Is there a way to get `gdaladdo`, `gdaldem` or another GDAL tool to create a  hillshade where each overview is shaded from the corresponding overview in the DEM rather than by resampling a single full size hillshade that's computed once?

A way to build turn a collection of different resolution images of the same extent into a single GeoTIFF with overviews would be sufficient.